# sql query to get result with exclude selected id

Tags: sql

i am stuck with sql query.
i want to select product from single table but exlude selected product.
i have wp_product table as

```
product_id   prod_name   prod_price   prod_rate
   1           xyz         100           5
   2           pqr         200           6 
   3           lmn         300           6
```

I am trying to execute this query

```
select * 
from wp_products 
where product_id <>'1' AND prod_price <=200 OR prod_rate='6'  OR 
          order by product_id DESC 
          LIMIT 4"
```

using this `select * from wp_products where product_id <>'1';` I get result

```
product_id    prod_name    prod_price  prod_rate
   2            pqr         200          6 
   3            lmn         300          6
```

and from this above result i want select(check) for all "OR" condition that i used in my tried query.

suggest me how can i get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly - just use parenthesis:

```
select * 
from wp_products 
where product_id <>'1' AND 
  (price<=200 OR wheel_size='6'  OR  studs='$studs') 
order by product_id DESC
```

Comment: :yes,i exactly want this.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try the sql below..

```
select * from wp_products
where (product_id <>'1') AND (price<=200 OR wheel_size='6' OR studs='$studs') 
order by product_id DESC LIMIT 4
```